# Simulating Booleans in Bison with C

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer

I am trying to make a logic calculator using C and bison, but I'm having trouble because C does not have a boolean type.

This is part of my Flex rules:

```
"TRUE" |
"T"    |
"t"  {yylval = 1; return TRUE; }

"FALSE" |
"F"    |
"f"  {yylval = 0; return TRUE; }
```

This is part of my Bison rules:

```
line:
        EOL
        | exp EOL {printf("%d %d %d \n"), $1, $2,$$;}
        ;

exp: TRUE
   | FALSE
   ;
```

This is the output when I type T followed by EOL (end of line) in my calculator:

```
10 12 1
```

10 is ascii for newline, 12 is ascii for carriage return and 1 is Ascii for start
I have the same output for F.

How can I make it so 1 is in $1 if I enter a T and 0 is in $1 if I enter a F?

Comment: For a start, you'll want to change the false return.

Comment: Could you post the full grammar, including all the %type, %union (etc..) declarations? What you've written looks fine to me, so my guess is that something might be wrong there.

Comment: C does have a boolean type as of 1999, it's name is `_Bool`. But it's neither really necessary nor extremely helpful. In C, the operands of the operators `&&` and `||` are implicitly converted to `int` 0 or `int` 1 based on their values (which is pretty much the same as first converting to `_Bool` and then to `int`). The same happens with the condition expressions in `if(condition-expr)`, `while(condition-expr)` and `for(;condition-expr;)`. Further, you can always invent or simulate your types.

Comment: C's bool(ean) type is irrelevant, this is a question about Bison and Flex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no Bison expert and it's been a long time since I've used it, so I suggest that you read [the Flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/) because I think your Flex is wrong. Your rules need to return a token type, not TRUE. In your Bison you have a FALSE token type, but no rule that returns that type. What you want is

```
exp: BOOLEAN
```

in Bison, and Flex rules that return BOOLEAN, not TRUE, for the boolean strings. You will also want

```
%token BOOLEAN

%%
```

at the beginning of your Bison file.

Take a look at the links on the right side of this page which show other people's questions about flex and bison.

Your comment "I'm having trouble because C does not have a boolean type" is incorrect and has misled people into giving you irrelevant advice about C's types.

Answer (score 2):

C *does have bool* as of the C99 standard. You can use the header `#include <stdbool.h>` and then use Boolean types in the following manner:

```
bool love = true;
if(love){
    //...
}
```

So, just like a standard bool.

Comment: This doesn't actually have anything to do with the OP's problem.

Comment: @JimBalter, true, but it seems his problem is being caused by a lack of boolean, so that's why I answered this.

Comment: No, lack of a boolean in C has nothing to do with the OP's problem.