# How to define a boolean in Flex

Tags: c, flex-lexer

I am building a compiler for a toy Java language (Decaf) and I am having trouble with defining a bool. When I try to analyze a boolean, it always returns false, whether or not I wrote false.

Flex code:

```
true|false  {
            yylval.boolConstant = yytext;
            return T_BoolConstant;
        }
```

Input code:

```
bool x = true;
bool y = false;
```

Output:

```
true         T_BoolConstant (value = false)
false        T_BoolConstant (value = false)
```

I tried searching on SO but this was the closest I could get to a proper answer:

[Simulating Booleans in Bison with C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12593750/simulating-booleans-in-bison-with-c/12593787#12593787)

Thank you!

**EDIT**: The output is coded in a separate c file that prints the string found in the test code, what kind of value it is (in this case it is a boolean or BooleanConstant) and then the value of the token that was saved. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: What type is `boolConstant`? How are you displaying things? The code you've shown doesn't display anything.

Comment: See http://sscce.org/

Comment: What type is `yylval.boolConstant`? That was the other thing I asked.

Comment: yylval.boolConstant is a bool

Comment: @GabeB-David: In C (and C++), any pointer can be converted to a boolean; `NULL` converts to `false`, and any other pointer converts to `true`. `yytext` is a pointer (to a character string, which is the current token) which is guaranteed to not be `NULL`. So draw your own conclusion :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to convert the strings `"true"` and `"false"` into the boolean constants `true` and `false`.  Otherwise you're just storing strings.

```
true {
    yylval.boolConstant = true;
    return T_BoolConstant;
}

false {
    yylval.boolConstant = false;
    return T_BoolConstant;
}
```

[Here is a similar question with a different approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22154353/lex-yacc-for-boolean-calculation).

Answer (score -1):

```
**Uson for the web services**   
 private var IsCity:Boolean = true;
    private function button_click():void {
        //dg.dataProvider= countrys
        webService.getCountries.send(1,0);

    }

    private function getCountries_result(evt:ResultEvent):void {

        //var countryList:ArrayCollection=evt.result as ArrayCollection;
                    dg.dataProvider=evt.result as ArrayCollection;

    }
    private function dgridclick():void{
    IsCity=false;
                webService.getSubLocationsByMultipleParameters.send(1,2,true,dg.selectedItem.id,dg.selectedItem.targetCode)

    }
    private function getState_result(evt:ResultEvent):void{

        if(IsCity)
            dg2.dataProvider=evt.result as ArrayCollection;
        else
            dg1.dataProvider=evt.result as ArrayCollection;

    }

    private function d1click():void{
      IsCity=true
    webService.getSubLocationsByMultipleParameters.send(1[4,3],false,dg1.selectedItem.id,dg1.selectedItem.targetCode);
    }
```