# How to define a boolean in Flex (2)

Tags: c, regex, flex-lexer

I am writing a scanner for my compiler project using [flex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flex_(lexical_analyser_generator)) and writing it in [decaf](https://parasol.tamu.edu/courses/decaf/students/decafOverview.pdf) (a language similar to C/C++ & Java), my scanner is up and running, except it fails in identifying boolean constants (true, false) I wrote below pattern and C code:

```
"true" { yylval.boolConstant = 1;
       return T_BoolConstant; }

"false" { yylval.boolConstant = 0;
        return T_BoolConstant; }
```

but instead of returning `T_BoolConstant` it keeps returning as `T_Identifier`. Basically scanner is recognizing both "true" & "false" as text valid to be considered as identifier not as boolean binary variable.

There is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35143459/5595994) answer for similar type of question but still it doesn't work for me!

Any guess why it isn't returning true/false ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be because you have your rule for identifiers above these rules. Flex matches rules top to bottom.